# Android “Not_Market_Managed” error

Tags: android, licensing, android-lvl

I have published my app in alpha mode. But i am getting this response while licensing my application. I have set the test accounts as well.I have set the License Test Response as "Licensed". But still getting the Not_Market_Managed error.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have incremented your version code in your app build.gradle file. If you are trying to publish a new version of your app and the version code is the same, you cannot publish.

Comment: I have version 2 released in alpha mode and and version 3 in development mode and still i am getting this issue. I havenot released any app on production.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new app and publish it? Or change the alpha app into a production one?

Comment: I am making a new application. But i have read that the app should be on playstore thats why i have uploaded apk in alpha mode to playstore for testing licensing.

Comment: Under defaultConfig in your build.gradle file make sure you increase this by 1. `versionCode 1`

Comment: i have upgraded the versionCode to 3, and on playstore app it is 2

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar story. In my case, I added a new flavor and applicationIdSuffix so the package name changed. I thought that the problem was that the application was not uploaded into the play market but when uploading it got an error : 
"Upload failed 
Your APK needs to have the package name _my_old_packagename_ ". Then I commented out the applicationIdSuffix and the problem was solved. The application did not even need to be uploaded since the application ran under the published account.